# Highlight gridpane Column

Tags: javafx

Okay so I'm trying to highlight all the nodes in a vertical column in a gridpane when I mouse over any node in the column. So right now I'm getting the columnIndex of the node my mouse is over and then creating an array of all nodes that share that column index. Return that array to the main method and then change the background color of the nodes in the array to a color.

This is the mouse over function:

```
for (Node node : officeHoursGridPane.getChildren()) {
                node.setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent t) -> {
                    node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#f9f3c5;");
                    Node source = (Node)t.getSource();
                    Integer colIndex =     GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
                    Integer rowIndex =     GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
                    //ystem.out.println("Column #: " + colIndex +     "\nRow #: " + rowIndex);                   
                    for(int c = 0; c <= colIndex; c++){
                        Node[] colNode = getNodeByColumnIndex(colIndex, officeHoursGridPane);
                        int colCount=0;
                        for(int v = 0; v <= colNode.length; v++){
                            Node vertNode = colNode[v];
                            vertNode.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#f9f3c5;");   
                        }                    
                    }                   
               });
                   node.setOnMouseExited((MouseEvent t) -> {
                      node.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#ffffff;");
                });          
            }
```

This is my Node[] builder:

```
    public Node[] getNodeByColumnIndex (final int column, GridPane gridPane) {
        Node[] result = null;
        ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridPane.getChildren();
        int count = 0;
        for (Node node : childrens) {
            if(GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == column) {
                result[count] = node;
                count++;
                if(count > column){
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: And the question is? Where is the problem?

Comment: Im trying to highlight the column of the node that my mouse is hovering over. Im getting no errors or anything. This is just how im attempting to implement it.

Comment: Im not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: @ShawnWilliams have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @Enigo yep that was it. Check the comments I added below your post

Comment: @ShawnWilliams that is great)

Comment: @Enigo thanks for your help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find all the nodes with the same column index in the gridpane's children:

```
for (Node node : officeHoursGridPane.getChildren()) {
    node.setOnMouseEntered(e -> officeHoursGridPane.getChildren().forEach(c -> {
        Integer targetIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
        if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(c) == targetIndex) {
            c.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#f9f3c5;");
        }
    }));
    node.setOnMouseExited(e -> officeHoursGridPane.getChildren().forEach(c -> {
        Integer targetIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
        if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(c) == targetIndex) {
            c.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#ffffff;");
        }
    }));
}
```

Note, that in order to not highlight extra nodes you probably should also check the row index as well.

Comment: This worked beautifully. It gave me the framework I needed. I purposely only wanted the column because I wanted to do some of the work myself. I just needed a place to start from.

Comment: I added in the Row Highlighting and limited both to show just a reversed L shape of highlight as per what I needed